# Is it possible to use doc_count as a term in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to get the display how many users viewed something once, twice,.. from a list of views.

It would look something like:

```
1 view: 1000 users
2 views: 100 users
3 views: 10 users
...
```

I can get the amount of views per user like so:

```
//request
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "views per token": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "browsertoken",
        "size": 0,
        "order": {
          "_count": "desc"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
//returns
{
   "took": 61,
   "timed_out": false,
   ...
   "hits": {
      "total": 215642,
      "max_score": 0,
      "hits": []
   },
   "aggregations": {
     "actions per token": {
     "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
     "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
     "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "co8976vymgarwwmianljqcch83ufecdi",
           "doc_count": 2479
        },
        {
           "key": "t2vc9j056fkihpvic0ty0rzzq7low29",
           "doc_count": 369
        },
   ...
```

But how do I get the count for the doc_count of the result of this aggregation ?

Comment: What woul `doc_count` as per your query return?

Comment: the amount of actions per "browsertoken", updated

Comment: You mean number of views??

Comment: yes, it's the same for this example, just updated